# Send resume as attachment to mail on click submit

Tags: php

I am sending resume through form to mail,but getting cannot send mail...pls check my code

This is my form:

```
<form action="Careers.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
    Name<br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_name" class="input"/><br />
    E-mail<br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_email" class="input"/><br />
    Upload your Resume<br />
    <input type="file" name="attachment" size="40"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="upload" class="color1"/>
    </form>
```

This is my Careers.php:

```
 <?php

  $strTo="bhargavi@genyedu.com";
  $strSubject = 'Job Application from a site visitor ';

   //*** Uniqid Session ***//

 $strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));
 $strHeader = "";
 $strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["cf_name"]."<".$_POST["cf_email"].">\nReply-To:           ".$_POST["cf_email"]."";

 $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

 $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";

 $strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";



 $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";

  $strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

  $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";





  //*** Attachment ***//

   if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] != "")

   {

    $strFilesName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];

    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]   ["tmp_name"])));

     $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";

     $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";

     $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";

      $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";

      $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";

      }



      $flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //



      if($flgSend)

       {

          echo "Mail send completed.";

        }

      else

        {

          echo "Cannot send mail.";

         }

       ?>
```

i am not getting any errors...but it says Cannot send mail...why i dont know...please help me.

If i remove '@' sign then i am getting fallowing error:

```
 Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\WebsiteTemplate3\Careers.php on line 63
```

hi...i disabled the smtp server authentication...now it says success but i didnt get any mail...but it says success...pls tell me

Comment: Try removing `@`...?!?

Comment: Check If mail get send without any file attachment ?

Comment: @deceze:if i remove @ errors are cmg.

Comment: @Rikesh:no i am not getting any mail

Comment: Are you saying that without `@` you are getting *useful error messages which tell you what's wrong?!* Then share them!

Comment: @deceze: iedited my question...there u can cjeck the error wat i am getting when i remove @ sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ sign in front of a function suppresses its error messages (it even says so in your code).
Try changing this:

```
@mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);
```

to this:

```
mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);
```

This will give you the error message saying what is going wrong, so you can fix it.

Comment: If i remove @,then i am getting the fallowing error:   Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\WebsiteTemplate3\Careers.php on line 63

Comment: Do you have a mailserver set up on the machine you are using?

Comment: yeah i have SMTP setup...

Comment: i installed SMTPmail on my machine...

Comment: Then check your settings in php.ini and such

Comment: its already configured in php.ini     [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

Comment: Have you tried setting the server to SMTP = 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: no i didnt tried that one...

Comment: i installed hmailserver on my machine...do u have any idea that how to configure...

Comment: hi...i disabled the smtp server authentication...now it says success but i didnt get any mail...but it says success...pls tell me

Comment: Well, getting a success message from the mail() function means that the mail is sent. Whatever happens from there is out of your hands. So it could be that your mailclient is not correct configured, or the emailaddress has an error in it. It can be useful to echo your mail function to the screen to see what it is actually doing: echo "mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader)";

Comment: i am getting this as echo:

Comment: mail(krishnabhargavi@gmail.com,Job Application from a site visitor ,null,From: abc Reply-To: bhargavi@genyedu.comMIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="2f2022d36c5a415abaee6c49909945f5" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. --2f2022d36c5a415abaee6c49909945f5 Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit --2f2022d36c5a415abaee6c49909945f5 Content-Type: application/octet-stream;name="tasks.txt" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tasks.txt"

Comment: MS5jb21wbGV0ZSBmdW5jdGlvbmFsaXR5Lihkb25lKQ0KMi5zZXQgYmFja2dyb3VuZCBjb2xvcnMg YW5kIGltYWdlcy4oVG9kYXkgdGFzaykNCjMuY2hlY2sgb25lIGlzIGl0IGxvb2tpbmcgZ29vZC4N CiBpZiBuby4NCjQuR28gZm9yIGFub3RoZXIgYXJjaGl0ZWN0dXJlLg0KDQoNCg0KDQo= )

Comment: Gmail filters quite heavily... Did you check your spamfilter? Also, Gmail can reject the message.

Comment: yeah..i got in spam...but i want in inbox...wat to do???

Comment: You can't do anything about that. If you mail me, I control where your message arrives, not you, nothing you can do about that. There are a few things you can do to make it less likely you will get into the spamfolder, but then you need to send via IMAP mailserver and a registered domain.

Comment: ok then i need to download IMAP mail server and configure

Comment: No, that will result in the same thing. Anyone can set up an IMAP mail server and start sending spam-mails. Use a valid emailaccount on a valid domain, and use that IMAP server.

Comment: sorry i didnt get u..valid email address means???

Comment: That the IP Address of your mailserver matches the IP of your domain. You are sending an email from server 1.1.1.1, but your domain is hosted on server 2.2.2.2 -> red flag for spamming.

Comment: ohh ohk..so wat i need to do now???

Comment: Use a valid emailaddress on a valid domain on a respected hostingcompany.

Comment: actually i am doing this process in localhost...not in server

Comment: Yes, and that is why gmail is spamlabeling your email. Otherwise, everyone could create a spamserver in just about 5 minutes.

Comment: ohk..if i do this process in server then it will work correctly???

Comment: Depending on the server you are using and how it is configured: yes. But this is indeed not something you can handle on your local computer. You can test it by setting your emailclients spamfilter to ignore your emails perhaps.